# Why it gives me a wrong index

Tags: c++

here is the text

"Abraham, Yohannes A.",Employee,

I want the index of second comma

here is my code `int    foundStatus = tempString.find_first_of(",", 8);`

I thought this will return the index of second comma after index 8 which is 22, but when i gives me -1 instead

Comment: How are you initializing `tempString`? It works [here](https://ideone.com/GwMkGY).

Comment: Show the full code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Oh - I'm sure that the OP has checked with its debugger to ensure that 'tempString' contains the exact text as described above.............

Comment: Wait is `,Employee` inside of the String? Otherwise it just stops after `A.`

Comment: yes it does inside of the String

Comment: what does tempString.size() return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) with 9 as second parameter, not 8 (assuming your string is: `"\"Abraham, Yohannes A.\", Employee, "`).
Otherwise it will just return 8 and not 22.
Return value [std::string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) (-1) means it could not find any comma afterwards - check your input string twice, that there is really a second comma after position 8.

The following code will output correctly 22:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::string tempString = "\"Abraham, Yohannes A.\", Employee, ";
  size_t firstComma = tempString.find_first_of(","); // firstComma = 8
  if (firstComma != std::string::npos) {
    size_t secondComma = tempString.find_first_of(",", firstComma+1);  // secondComma = 22
    std::cout << secondComma << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the whole temp string is "Abraham, Yohannes A.",Employee,$120000.00,Per Annum,SPECIAL ASSISTANT TO THE PRESIDENT AND CHIEF OF STAFF FOR THE OFFICE OF PUBLIC ENGAGEMENT AND INTERGOVERNMENTAL AFFAIRS       so i think there is comma after position 8

Comment: i use 9 or greater but still return -1

Comment: and why you add \" in the temp string tho?

Comment: oh shit just found out temp string does don't have any element after 8

Comment: @ckmss Because double quotes within literal string's must be escaped.